# Compare part of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

How do I compare a part of a string - for example if I want to compare if string A is part of string B. I would like to find out this: When `string A = "abcd"` and `string B = "abcdef"` it needs to return true. How do I do that in JavaScript? If I use `substring(start, end)` I do not know what values to pass to the `start` and `end` parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to give more description like and some examples or codes

Answer (score 27):

You can use `indexOf`:

```
if ( stringB.indexOf( stringA ) > -1 ) {
  // String B contains String A
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Like this:

```
var str = "abcdef";
if (str.indexOf("abcd") >= 0)
```

Note that this is case-sensitive.
If you want a case-insensitive search, you can write

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("abcd") >= 0)
```

Or,

```
if (/abcd/i.test(str))
```

And a general version for a case-insensitive search, you can set strings of any case

```
if (stringA.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringB.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 18):

Javascript ES6/ES2015 has `String.includes()`, which has nearly all browser compatibility [except for IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-string-includes). (But what else is new?)

```
let string = "abcdef";
string.includes("abcd"); //true
string.includes("aBc"); //false - .includes() is case sensitive
```

Comment: That's why God gave us Babel.

Comment: what if we want to check that the partial string is at the beginning of the full length string?

Comment: @SteveW Then you use a different function listed in other answers, like `indexOf`

Answer (score 5):

Using indexOf or match is unnecessarily slow if you are dealing with large strings and you only need to validate the beginning of the string. A better solution is to use startsWith() or its equivalent function-- from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
      position = position || 0;
      return this.substr(position, searchString.length) === searchString;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`"abcdef".indexOf("abcd") !== -1` should be okay

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expression might help you.

```
var patt = new RegExp(stringA, 'i');
if(stringB.match(patt)){                            
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the javascript search also

```
if( stringA.search(stringB) > -1){
}
```