# Filter through large arrray (3000+) objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a json file that lists about 3000 objects. Every object is an airport. I would like to create a function where a user can filter out a single airport by typing in a name.

This is what I came up with

```
<input (keyup)="searchAirport(searchquery)" [(ngModel)]="searchquery" id="searchAirport"/>
<span>{{searchedAirport}}</span>
```

component

```
searchedAirport: string;

this.http.request('/assets/resources/airportsraw.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
      this.airportsArray = data;
  });

searchAirport(value) {
  for (const i of this.airportsArray) {
    if (value === i.name ) {
      this.searchedAirport = i.name;
    }
  }
}
```

This does return the correct Aiport name but it has 2 downsides. It only works if you search with a capital. So `barcelona` won't return anything, but `Barcelona` will.

And the second downside is that it only returns if the value is completely equal to the airport name.

How would I return a value based on a partial search? So `Bar` instead of `Barcelona` and how could I get arround the capital problem?

Comment: what if their are multiple matches starting with Bar ?

Comment: Then it should return all the results that have `Bar` in them. So the user should just type to get more specific results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833944/compare-part-of-string)

Comment: @Caramiriel: although there is some overlap, I wouldn't call this a duplicate.  If nothing else, this adds the entire issue of filtering a list.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
const findMatches = (values) => test => {
  const regex = new RegExp(test, 'i'); 
  return values.filter(val => regex.test(val.name))
}

const searchAirports = findMatches(airports);
```

Obviously you could inline the `findMatches` function, but I think it's more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore cases:

value.toLowerCase() === i.name.toLowerCase()

For partial searches then you  might need to use a regular expression (Regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in the following way

```js
let arr = ['abc', 'abd', 'Abe', 'bcd', 'cde', 'edf'];

let input = 'ab';
let re = new RegExp('^' + input, 'i');

let result = arr.filter(e => e.match(re) != null);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I use your array it works fine, but when I use my array I get `ERROR TypeError: e.match is not a function`. The objects in my array look like this `{id: "100", name: "Ottawa Macdonald Cartier Intl", iata: "YOW", icao: "CYOW", lon: "-75.669167", …`

Comment: try e.name.match()

Comment: Rather than `e.match(re) != null` (with or without the `name` property), did you consider `re.test(e.name)` which seems a better choice for `filter`?

Answer (score 0):

To search for a large amount of data on front end, this is what I did on javascript side -

1. Lets say your array of data (JSON object) looks like `['abcd', 'abfer', 'xyds', 'irkd',...]` (more than 10,0000 elements) - `array1`
2. While you load your array from json, create a javascript array, which is a 2-D array of 26 length, and at each index, store index of element for each char. For example, for above array, your new array looks like this -`[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0], [0, 2, 3], [1], [1], [], [], ...]` - `array2`
   Meaning - char 'a' exists in 0th element and 1st element, char 'd' exists in 0, 2, 3 element.

   Now your object is ready, and page is ready for quick search.

When user types search string, onkeyup you do this -

1. Lets say user search for `'bf'`
2. From your array in step 2, load arrays for char `b` and char `f`, and take the intersection of both. You will now have all the position of all the elements which have char `b` and char `f` - `intersected`
3. Now you iterate over your intersection array, go directly at those indexes in your original array (from step 1), and do indexOf('bf')

   `//pseudo code
   var t = 0;
   $.each(intersected, function(k, v){
         if(array1[k].indexOf(searchString) > -1){
             results[t++] = array1[k];
         }
   });
   return results;`

This way you dont iterate over all the elements in your array. You only iterate over the elements which will have the chars user searched for.

To provide case-insensitive search, convert everything `toLowerCase()`, while preparing your `array2`, and while searching

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
          product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

This will do a case insensitive filter and will return all items containing any of the defined text.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example code. It may help you.

```
filterData(search){

    var data = [{
            "id":1,
            "category":"mycategory"
           },
           {        
                "id":2,
                "category":"second"
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "category": "thirdcat"
            }];

    return returnedData = $.grep(data, function(element, index){
        search = search.toLowerCase();
        var elementCategory = element.category.toLowerCase();
        if(elementCategory.indexOf(search) !== -1){
            return element;
        }

    });


}
```