# Check if string matches

Tags: javascript, if-statement, constants, reduce

I've got a dataset, and each object has a `promoUrl` and a `promoNumber`, structured like so:

```
const phoneNumbers = [
  {
    promoUrl: '/interior-doors/',
    promoNumber: '589-918-0710',
  },
  {
    promoUrl: '/promo4/',
    promoNumber: '307-789-8615',
  },
];
```

On first load a cookie is set, containing the `referral` url (the `const` `referrer` in the code below) and the referral URL is passed to a `reduce` function allowing me to look for a URL, find the associated phone number, and then display that number dynamically.

```
const url = referrer;

const promoNumber = promoResults.reduce((promoNumber: string, results: any) => {
  const hasPromo = url === results.promoUrl;

  if (hasPromo) {
    return results.promoNumber;
  }
    return promoNumber;
}, '');
```

However right now when it finds the URL it will only match the number if the cookie value matches the `promoUrl` exactly. Once this is live I won't be in charge of setting the promoUrls, and that task will go to non-developers. How do I set this so it works as long as the string contains matching characters, i.e. instead of needing `/interior-doors/` it would work if the `promoUrl` is `interior-doors` or `/interior-doors`? Really anything so long as the string includes matching characters?

I've tried editing my `hasPromo` `const` using `.includes()`:

`const hasPromo = url.includes(results.promoUrl);`

But it still hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare part of string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833944/compare-part-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately no, it seems as though modifying my `hasPromo` `const` with `const hasPromo = url.includes(results.promoUrl);` still doesn't work unless the url matches perfectly. Modified my question to include this info.

Comment: Try `IndexOf()`.  It's illustrated in the first answer of the post I linked.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't seem to be working for it. It only functions if the `URL` is perfectly matched.

Comment: Figured it out! Adding an answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out after a bit of digging and some help in the comments from Robert Harvey.

All I need to do was modify the `hasPromo` `const` to check `results.promoUrl` first.

`const hasPromo = results.promoUrl.includes(url);`

This worked exactly like I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

have you log your url and results.promoUrl
suggestion is logs type and value of both keys ( url and promoUrl)